# SQL select where multiple condition by same id from one table with two condition

Tags: sql, where-clause

please help me, I have a table like below and I want to get data by id with 2 condition :

1. `responded` => get id where `status ='sent'` and `status = ''` and `status = 'delivered'`
2. `pending` => get id where `status ='sent'` and `status = 'delivered`, not with `status = ''`

| message_thread_id | status |
| --- | --- |
| 229 |  |
| 229 | delivered |
| 229 | sent |
| 229 | delivered |
| 229 | delivered |
| 240 | sent |
| 240 | sent |
| 1044 |  |
| 1044 |  |
| 1044 |  |
| 1068 | delivered |

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - What are your tries so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good way to do this, but is a good start to begin to think.

I would think in a temporal table inside an stored procedure. But your
question doesn't specify because you don't have any tries.

I would make a table with several columns that indicates if the user has the specific state in true or false, populate it and then filter by a query.

But anyway, here is the "start to think" query:

```
SELECT 
    message_thread_id, 'responded' as status 
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    message_thread_id IN (SELECT message_thread_id 
                          FROM table WHERE status = 'sent')
    AND message_thread_id IN (SELECT message_thread_id 
                              FROM table WHERE status = '')
    AND message_thread_id IN (SELECT message_thread_id 
                              FROM table WHERE status = 'delivered')

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    message_thread_id, 'pending' as status 
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    message_thread_id IN (SELECT message_thread_id FROM table 
                          WHERE status = 'sent')
    AND message_thread_id NOT IN (SELECT message_thread_id 
                                  FROM table WHERE status = '')
    AND message_thread_id IN (SELECT message_thread_id 
                              FROM table WHERE status = 'delivered')
```

Comment: i try for responded :
SELECT *, 'responded' FROM message a WHERE week(created_at) = week(now()) and NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT 1 FROM message b 
   WHERE a.message_thread_id = b.message_thread_id
   AND status = 'sent' and status = '' and status = 'delivered'
)

Comment: Well, seems to be similar on my answer. But I would try to reduce the subqueries with the -store procedure- idea.